# ¿Cómo pongo diferentes símbolos para distintos grupos en una gráfica?

Tags: r, gráficas

Tengo que graficar un nmds hecho con `vegan`, os muestro el código:

```
nmds.tabla <- metaMDS(tabla, trymax=100)
plot(nmds.tabla, display=c("sites"))
```

Dentro del objeto `tabla` tengo una categoría llamada 'Substrate' con valores de 1 a 3 y lo que necesito es que en la gráfica que sale de `plot(nmds.tabla, ...)` los puntos que me saca el comando los coloree con distintos colores según si pertenecen a una u otra categoría del parámetro "Substrate". Idealmente deberían tener también diferentes formas, pero supongo que lo que haya que usar para los colores será extrapolable a las formas, ¿no?

No tengo mucha idea acerca de modificar gráficos básicos en R, así que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

P.d.: El objeto `tabla` tiene más o menos esta pinta:

```
                   m4         m6    Core_m7          m8       m10        m11 
Substrate 1.000000000 1.00000000 2.00000000 1.000000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
Fluoride  0.018700499 0.02489596 0.03422726 0.046104787 0.0366289 0.04178732
Acetate   0.275080898 0.26764098 0.12678058 0.258158193 0.2474823 0.12580646
Formiate  0.182414652 0.23879856 0.39724458 0.569256833 0.5483894 0.74067843
Chloride  0.078456818 0.22115332 0.20194306 0.132579848 0.1395643 0.08955188
Nitrate   0.009025742 0.01619735 0.01452054 0.006037955 0.0000000 0.00000000 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no te entendí mal, tienes algo como esto:

```
library("vegan")

tabla <- read.table(text="comunity m4 m6 Core_m7 m8 m10 m11
Substrate 1.000000000 1.00000000 2.00000000 1.000000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
Fluoride  0.018700499 0.02489596 0.03422726 0.046104787 0.0366289 0.04178732
Acetate   0.275080898 0.26764098 0.12678058 0.258158193 0.2474823 0.12580646
Formiate  0.182414652 0.23879856 0.39724458 0.569256833 0.5483894 0.74067843
Chloride  0.078456818 0.22115332 0.20194306 0.132579848 0.1395643 0.08955188
Nitrate   0.009025742 0.01619735 0.01452054 0.006037955 0.0000000 0.00000000", 
                    header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE, row.names=1)

nmds.tabla <- metaMDS(tabla, trymax=100)
plot(nmds.tabla, display=c("sites"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguramente con muchos más datos, lo que buscas entonces es configurar el símbolo y color de estos puntos. Se me ocurre hacer algo como esto:

```
# Determinamos la fila de la categoria deseada
idx <- which(rownames(nmds.tabla$points) == "Substrate")
# Generamos un vector con los simbolos y colores para todas las categorias
pchs <- rep(18, nrow(nmds.tabla$points))
colors <- rep("black", nrow(nmds.tabla$points))
# Establecemos una configuración particular para la categoría deseada
pchs[idx] <- 19
colors[idx] <- "red"

# Primero dibujamos un plot en blanco
plot(nmds.tabla, type='n')
# Luego los puntos
points(nmds.tabla, 
       display = 'sites', 
       pch = pchs, 
       col = colors)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es graficarlo con ggplot que proporciona opciones para personalizarlo como uno quiera.

Esto implica preparar la data antes:

```
library("vegan")
tabla <- read.table(text="comunity m4 m6 Core_m7 m8 m10 m11
Substrate 1.000000000 1.00000000 2.00000000 1.000000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
Fluoride  0.018700499 0.02489596 0.03422726 0.046104787 0.0366289 0.04178732
Acetate   0.275080898 0.26764098 0.12678058 0.258158193 0.2474823 0.12580646
Formiate  0.182414652 0.23879856 0.39724458 0.569256833 0.5483894 0.74067843
Chloride  0.078456818 0.22115332 0.20194306 0.132579848 0.1395643 0.08955188
Nitrate   0.009025742 0.01619735 0.01452054 0.006037955 0.0000000 0.00000000", 
                    header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE, row.names=1)

nmds.tabla <- metaMDS(tabla, trymax=100)

data.scores <- as.data.frame(scores(nmds.tabla))
data.scores$site <- rownames(data.scores)
```

Una vez está listo, se grafica con ggplot:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data = data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, 
shape = site, colour = site), size = 3) + coord_equal() + theme_bw()
```

Se personaliza como uno desee.